# replacing a substring in a string: Python

Tags: python, string, substring

I am trying to continuously replace the substrings within a string based on user input but my string.replace syntax seems to replace the whole string with the substring from user input. here is the code:

```
import re
secret_word  = 'COMPUTER'    
clue = len(secret_word) * '-'   # this step gives the user the nos of characters in secret_word
user_guess = input("Type a single letter here, then press enter: ")
user_guess = user_guess.upper()
if user_guess in secret_word:
    index = [match.start() for match in re.finditer(user_guess, secret_word)] # this finds the index of the user guess in secret_word                                                     
    print(index)
    for i in index:
        clue  = clue.replace(clue[i], user_guess)
        print("The word now looks like this: "+ clue)
```

I am not sure why it is not replacing only the substrings.

Comment: Can u show us a sample input & expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is the line `clue  = clue.replace(clue[i], user_guess)`. `clue[i]` will always be equal to `'*'` at the beginning so the replace function will replace all the characters by the user_guess.

One solution is to change `clue` to be a list instead of a string `clue = len(secret_word) * ['-']`
and replace the replace operation by `clue[i] = user_guess`

Do not forget to update the print operation: `clue` becomes `"".join(clue)` in `print("The word now looks like this: "+ clue)`

Answer (score 1):

```
secret_word  = 'COMPUTER'
clue = str(len(secret_word) * '-')   # this step gives the user the nos of characters in secret_word
user_guess = input("Type a single letter here, then press enter: ")
user_guess = user_guess.upper()

if user_guess in secret_word:
    index = user_guess.find(user_guess) # this finds the index of the user guess in secret_word
    clue = clue[:index] + user_guess + clue[index+1:]
    print("The word now looks like this: " + clue)
```

Try this, you don't need a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks, Sachin for this response. There is one problem i still face though. This solution only works if the substring being replaced occurs only once in the string. How would one write the code for it to update all instances of a particular substring within a string. For example, with your solution, if secret_word is 'HAPPY', when the user inputs 'P', only the first occurence of P would be updated in the variable 'clue'.

Comment: @O.Edward seems you have accepted the answer do you still want me to solve it again?

Answer (score 0):

In python, when you use `str.replace(x, substitution)`, it replaces every occurrence of `x` with the `substituion` in the string `str`.

In the beginning the variable `clue` holds the `--------` string, because of which your replace method is called as `clue.replace('-', U)` considering, user provided the input `u`, which in turn replace the every occurence of `-` i.e. the whole string `clue` to `UUUUUUUU`.

One way to achieve this would be to change your code to something like this:

```
import re
secret_word = 'COMPUTER'
clue = len(secret_word) * '-'   # this step gives the user the nos of characters in secret_word
user_guess = input("Type a single letter here, then press enter: ")
user_guess = user_guess.upper()
if user_guess in secret_word:
    index = [match.start() for match in re.finditer(user_guess, secret_word)]  # this finds the index of the user guess in secret_word
    print(index)
    for i in index:
        clue = clue[:i] + user_guess + clue[i:]
        print("The word now looks like this: "+ clue)
```